# NextJs ClerkJS looping issue

Tags: authentication, next.js

I get this message after i click google and login using clerkJS

[image: error image]

After clicking "Get Started," I enter ClerkJs, which then redirects me to the Gmail login page. Once I log in to my Gmail account, it automatically logs me into my application. However, I'm facing an issue where, upon clicking Google on ClerkJs, my application keeps refreshing in a loop around five times. Eventually, I receive an error message. I'm unsure about what I might be doing incorrectly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably in a redirection loop, meaning page a -> page b & page b -> page a.

Please checkout the code for this, I've been there and it's tricky at times